# Use CSS/IMG/JS with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I create a http server with nodeJS and express. 
I do the router for html pages but the css, the images and the js files are ignored.

I checked and the paths are ok.

I  tried to use static function of express but it doesn't work.

If you have an idea :)

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var fs = require('fs');
//var express = require('express');
//var app = express();

//app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/views/web/assets/img"));

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) 
{
    var pathName = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
    console.log(__dirname + "/views/web" + pathName);
    fs.readFile( __dirname + "/views/web" + pathName , "utf8" , function(error , file){
     if(error) {
          res.writeHead(404 , {"Content-Type" : "text/html" }); 
          res.end();
     }else{
          res.writeHead(200 , {"Content-Type" : "text/html" }); 
          res.write(file);
          res.end();
     }      
    });
});

server.listen(1337);
console.log("Serveur web lancé sur localhost:1337 ...");
```

An extract of login.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Profile - Login</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/logo.png" />
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP STYLES-->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- FONTAWESOME STYLES-->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- CUSTOM STYLES-->
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

</head>
```

The verification of paths :

```
proux@DESKTOP-VDRS1QF:/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server$ node server.js
Serveur web lancé sur localhost:1337 ...
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/login.html
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/css/bootstrap.css
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/css/font-awesome.css
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/css/custom.css
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/js/custom.js
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/img/nom_blanc.png
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/img/logo.png
```

Elodie

Comment: you can't serve files that aren't html with a content type of text/html

Comment: Oh yes I totally forgot this line... How can I check if it is html ? And if it is not html file I just have to delete this line?

Comment: [**How to serve static files (ExpressJS)**](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're express static is serving /public, what is under that? Because I noticed that you had this originally:

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/views/web/assets/img"));
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/logo.png" />
```

You should have something like this instead:

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/views/web"));
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/img/logo.png" />
```

given your path looks like:

```
/mnt/d/Users/Elodie/Desktop/server/views/web/assets/img/logo.png
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the content type for the files.

Comment: How can I check if it is html file ? And if it is not html file I just have to delete this line : res.writeHead(200 , {"Content-Type" : "text/html" });?

Comment: @Elodie You can check the extension with the path module. JS is text/javascript, CSS is text/css. More content-type info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types